# Portable install for use on Raspberry Pi

Tags: installing, portability

I would like to install TeXLive as a portable installation on a USB drive and then use it on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (a modified version of Debian). The SD card I am using for the Pi's "hard drive" is not big enough to hold a TeX installation, so I would like to use the USB.

The Raspberry Pi uses an ARM1176JZFS processor, as described on the [project's website](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#introWhatIs).

I know how to select the portable installation in `install-tl` on the command-line (on Debian GNU/Linux), but which binary should I install? (`armel-linux`?)

EDIT: 
[Debian's notes on the Raspberry Pi](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi) suggest `armel`. I will try and update if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `armel-linux` binaries work on my Raspberry Pi. After mounting the drive I added the path to the arm binaries (under `texlive/bin`) to the search path in `.profile` and it worked fine.

Another option for Pi users, of course, would be just to install Debian's `texlive` packages via `aptitude`/`apt` on the Pi, but those packages are out of date and I wanted to save space on the disk.